# Why does this Arduino compatible not have all the recommended capacitors?

Tags: arduino, capacitor, decoupling-capacitor

One of the sources I'm using as reference material in designing a new Arduino-compatible board is the Sparkfun SAMD21 dev breakout board (https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Boards/sparkfun-samd21-pro-breakout-v10.pdf). I've also been using the datasheet for the SAMD21 as my (main) reference, and it seems that the Sparkfun board is violating the recommended values and even leaving some caps off.

[image]

For example, the VDDCORE capacitor is rated only 0.1uF instead of the 1uF in the datasheet, and both of the 10uF capacitors are missing. Is this a mistake or possibly a cost cutting measure? How will the performance be affected?

Comment: As well as cost-cutting measures, there have been periodic shortages of various types of ceramic capacitors in recent years and it's possible the board was designed during such a period.

Answer (score 7):

Those are rules of thumb to guide you, Not hard design rules. If you want to know what's actually required it takes a lot more analysis of the actual PCB layout and use which is often not feasible.

In fact, ideally, you're not actually supposed to use varying sizes of capacitors at all due to resonant peaking. You're supposed to use the capacitor that has sufficiently low inductance to decoupling the high frequencies which are of interest (which usually means low capacitance) and then put a lot of them in parallel so their total capacitance is enough to decoupling your low frequencies. As you can imagine, this is a pain but you cannot get away with less on very fast processors and FPGAs.

The lower value capacitors (actually smaller package capacitors rather than value) tend to correlate with lower parasitic inductance and will be effective for decoupling high frequencies at low powers. This corresponds with reduced EMI and high frequency noise.

The larger value capacitors (actually larger package capacitors) tend to correlate with higher parasitic inductance so will not be effective for the higher frequencies, but the higher capacitance means they can more cost and space effectively handle decoupling for higher power such as momentary brownouts.

Insufficient decoupling of either can result in misbehaviour.

Also, it is a cost cutting measure. 10uF ceramic caps aren't cheap.

Answer (score 3):

C5 (2.2uF) on U3 was used instead of 10uF exclusions.
U3 has a load regulation of 1%V @ 600mA might be 33mV is worst case and typical is 0.2% which means this Diodes Inc LDO should work well with 2.2uF and no need for the 10uF's.

But as expected these changes are about cost reduction.